# Get sibling view from constructor

Tags: android

Let's assume I have layout like this

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <MyListView />
    <RelativeLayout />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there any chance to properly get inner `RelativeLayout` from `MyListView` constructor which is extended `ListView`?

Simply `findViewById(R.id....)` returns `null`.

Comment: Did you use myListView.getParent().findViewById()??

Comment: var = (RelativeLayout) ((ViewGroup) getParent()).findViewById(R.id....); throws `NullPointerException`
Remind: I want to do it from inside of ListView constructor, I guess it matters alot.

Comment: The inflater parses the layout in order so the inner RelativeLayout isn't available at that moment. You could try placing the inner RelativeLayout before the ListView if you can and see how it goes.

Comment: no because inner RelativeLayout may not be created yet, and even if it was it may not be attached to any parent

Comment: @pskink by "no" you mean it's not possible?

Comment: @Luksprog I have tried that but as well no luck. Can I somehow force inflater to make sure it will be created and attached?

Comment: why do you need it in the ctor?